# Checking an array for existing array items passed as a parameter

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 react functions below

```
     const hasPermission = (permission: string) => {
        if (user?.permissionsEnabled === false) {
          return true
        }
        return permissions.includes(permission) || false
      }
```

The function below accepts an array of a particular type

I want a situation where if any item in the array passed here(parameter) exist in the enum
UserPermissions I want to return a true.
return true does not seem to be working in the method below.

```
      const hasAnyPermission = (permissionsPassed: UserPermissions[]) => {
        permissionsPassed.map(permission => {
          if (hasPermission(permission)) {
            return true
          }
        })
        return false
      }
```

I am calling hasAnyPermission like this..

```
    hasAnyPermission([Edit,View])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) only returns an array, you need to use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead:

```js
const hasAnyPermission = (permissionsPassed: UserPermissions[]) => {
  return permissionsPassed.some(permission => {
    if (hasPermission(permission)) {
      return true
    }
  })
}
```

Which is equivolent to:

```js
const hasAnyPermission = (permissionsPassed: UserPermissions[]) => {
  return permissionsPassed.some(permission => hasPermission(permission));
}
```

---

Or use the regular for-of loops:

```js
const hasAnyPermission = (permissionsPassed: UserPermissions[]) => {
  for(let permission of permissionsPassed) {
    if (hasPermission(permission)) {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}
```

Comment: Yes, pick whichever you like

Answer (score 0):

Abbreviated fully-working example:

```
enum UserPermissions { Edit, View, Delete }
const user = { permissions: [UserPermissions.View] }
console.log("has permission?", hasAnyPermission(user, [UserPermissions.Delete]))

function hasAnyPermission(user, permissions: UserPermissions[]) {
  if (user?.permissionsEnabled === false) return true
  const userHasPermission = (p) => user.permissions.includes(p)
  return permissions.some(userHasPermission)
}
```